# Store is undefine after extjs sdk

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

my mvc applications works fine. However when i run the sdk. I get store is undefined.

Below the store is defined as "Cutters" I've also tried the full name namespace "Mis.store.Cutters"

I've uploaded the whole file. [all-classes.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdvlqkwq9y9q4bg/all-classes.txt)

here is my view "Cutter"

```
Ext.define('Mis.view.Cutter', {    extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
alias:'widget.Cutter',
items:[
    {
        border:0,
        width:950,
        layout:{
            align:'stretch',
            type:'hbox'
        },
        items:[
            {
                xtype:'gridpanel',
                title:'',
                id:'cutterGrid',
                name:'cutterGrid',
                layout:{
                    align:'stretch',
                    type:'hbox'
                },
                store:'Cutters',
                columns:[
                    {
                        xtype:'gridcolumn',
                        dataIndex:'CutterNumber',
                        text:'Cutter',
                        flex:1,
                        sortable: true
                    }
                ],
                bbar:Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
                        id: 'cutterPagination',
                        name: 'cutterPagination',
                        store:'Cutters',
                        displayInfo:true,
                        displayMsg:'Displaying records {0} - {1} of {2} &nbsp;',
                        emptyMsg:"No records to display&nbsp;"
                    }
                )


            }
        ]
    }


],
initComponent:function () {
    this.callParent();
}
```

});

app.js

```
    Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });
Ext.Loader.setPath('App', '/ext/Cutter/app');
Ext.application({

    name: 'Mis',
    appFolder: '/ext/Cutter/app',
    models: [ 'Cutter', 'Project', 'CutterHistory','Job', 'Part' , 'ClientFinder'],
    stores: [ 'Cutters','CutterHistories','Projects', 'Jobs', 'Parts'],
    controllers: ['Cutter'],
    launch: function () {
        Ext.QuickTips.init();
        var cmp1 = Ext.create('Mis.view.ViewCutter', {
            renderTo: "mis-application"
        });
        cmp1.show();
    }

});
```

"ViewCutter" this view has reference to "Cutter" which  is the view i have the store undefined in.

```
    Ext.define('Mis.view.ViewCutter', {
    extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
    height:700,
    id:'Cutter',
    border: 0,
    width:950,
    layout:{
        align:'stretch',
        type:'vbox'
    },
    title:'',
    requires:[
        'Mis.view.Cutter',
        'Mis.view.EditCutter'
    ],
    initComponent:function () {
        var me = this;
        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items:[
                {
                    xtype:'panel',

                    flex:1,
                    title:'',

                    items:[
                        {
                            xtype:'Cutter',
                            border:0,
                            layout:{
                                type:'column'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'EditCutter',
                            border:0,
                            layout:{
                                type:'column'
                            }

                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]

        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: i've added the app.js. So app.js creates "Mis.view.ViewCutter" this has an xtype "Cutter". This undefined store is in "Cutter"

Comment: Do you have your store defined in any of the controllers store configs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that i had the store defined on the Pagination.

```
 bbar:Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
                        id: 'cutterPagination',
                        name: 'cutterPagination',
                        **store:'Cutters',**
                        displayInfo:true,
                        displayMsg:'Displaying records {0} - {1} of {2} &nbsp;',
                        emptyMsg:"No records to display&nbsp;"
                    }
```

This didn't seem to be an issue before i use the sdk. In hindsight i wish i was using the sdk from the start.